# Multi-threaded Rectangle Packing(use Openmp or other)

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I want my code have multi-thread to solve it, but I don’t know if my idea can be implemented . Does anyone can help me? Thank you.

I have a binary tree structure. It is a representation to rectangle packing. I use DFS(preorder) to traversal my tree. Root node be placed on the bottom left. Depends on the left or right node, place the node(block). Use the following rules to determine the x coordinate:
(1)left node: place it in the right hand of parent(x=xparent+Wparent)
(2)right node: place it on the upper of parent(x = xparent)
By the way, the y coordinate be determined by the contour line. The contour line is the shape constructed by the previous nodes(block).

Now I want to divide my tree into two parts, one is left subtree, another is right subtree. I use two threads to traversal respectively, so I can place two blocks in the same time. After get the "x" respectively, I should check if they will overlap each other. If they don't overlap I can place two block in once, or I should do place in sequential. What I try to do is adding some comparison to check before function `checkY`.

I am very grateful for your patience.

```
void dfsContour(NODE* node, NODE* parent, int x, char type){
    if(node == nullptr) return;
    else{
        if(type == 'R'){
            //std::cout << "left child" << std::endl;
            node->block->x = x + parent->getWidth();
            checkY(node->getX(), node);
        }
        else{
            //std::cout << "right child" << std::endl;
            node->block->x = x;
            checkY(node->getX(), node);
        }
    }    
    dfsContour(node->left, node, node->getX(), 'R');
    dfsContour(node->right, node, node->getX(), 'U');
    return;
}    

void dfsContour(){
    /*Clear all the contour?*/
    CONTOURNODE* temp = new CONTOURNODE();
    while(head->next != nullptr){
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    root->block->x = 0;
    checkY(root->getX(), root);
    NODE* leftnode = root->left;
    NODE* rightnode = root->right;
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        if(omp_get_thread_num() ==0 ){
            dfsContour(leftnode,root,root->getX(),'R');
        }
        else{
            dfsContour(rightnode,root,root->getX(),'U');
        }
        
    }
    #pragma omp barrier
    return;
}
```

Comment: You have a `parallel` region but no worksharing construct. You should for instance make the two `contour` calls into tasks. Btw, DFS is usually very hard to parallelize because it is intrinsically very sequential.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Hi, thanks for your comment. I don't understand "make the two contour calls into tasks". Could you give me some examples?It  is `#pragma omp task` for 'dfsContour'?  . Because tree is just my representation of packing, if I change order it doesn't matter.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter then you have indeed parallel operations and you can turn them into tasks.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout So I don't need `parallel` region, I need `task` region? Sorry, I am so confuse. I should ask more clearly...

Comment: Tasks are not trivial. Read a tutorial.

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.